# Java Q based on Packages

Tags: java

A UNIX user named Bob wants to replace his chess program with a new one, but he is not sure where the old one is installed. Bob is currently able to run a Java chess program starting from his home directory /home/bob using the command:

`java -classpath /test:/home/bob/downloads/*.jar games.Chess`

Bob's CLASSPATH is set (at login time) to:

`/usr/lib:/home/bob/classes:/opt/java/lib:/opt/java/lib/*.jar`

What is a possible location for the Chess.class file?

```
A. /test/Chess.class 
B. /home/bob/Chess.class 
C. /test/games/Chess.class 
D. /usr/lib/games/Chess.class 
E. /home/bob/games/Chess.class 
F. inside jarfile /opt/java/lib/Games.jar (with a correct manifest) 
G. inside jarfile /home/bob/downloads/Games.jar (with a correct manifest)


Answer is C but I want to know how it is ...........
```

Answer (score 6):

The classpath is explicitely passed to the java command, so it supersedes the CLASSPATH environment variable. Answers B, D, E and F are thus incorrect.

A is incorrect since the class name is `games.Chess`. Since the package and the directory structures must match, the Chess.class file must be in a games folder (inside or outside a jar file).

C is correct.

G is incorrect because you can't pass *.jar to a classpath. And even if Games.jar was explicitely in the classpath, the manifest doesn't play any role here.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html for the documentation about the classpath.

Comment: What do you mean by "G is incorrect because you can't pass *.jar to a classpath" . I think that's what we are doing here so that java command can look for appropriate class file inside jar

Comment: Read the link I gave in the answer. You can pass `-cp /foo/*`, but not `-cp /foo/*.jar`.

Comment: So what happens when we specify /foo/*.jar?

Comment: I guess Java searches for a file literally named *.jar in /foo, or ignores that part of the classpath.